# Error: Undefined first referenced symbol in file

Tags: c++, pointers, nachos

I get this error and I'm not sure how to fix it.  The request constructor takes a string type, I don't think I implemented properly in my request.h file. 
Error:

```
Undefined           first referenced
 symbol                 in file
Request::Request(char *, int, int)  threadtest.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to nachos
```

code:

```
class Request
{
 public:
  //constructor intializes request type                                                              

  Request(char *u, int rqtID, int rqtrID);
  char *url;
  int requestID;
  int requesterID;


};
```

request.cc file where constructor is defined

```
#include "request.h"

    Request :: Request(char *urll, int requestIDD, int requesterIDD )
    {
      url = *urll
      requestID = requestIDD;
      requesterID = requesterIDD;

    }
```

Comment: Where did you define the constructor definition ? Are you compiling and linking that source file ?

Comment: Your `Request` constructor has no function body

Comment: Make sure `request.cc` is included in the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try to understand the error first.

> **ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors.** No output written to nachos

This means it is a linking issue. Linker is unable to find definitions for some symbols.

> Undefined first referenced symbol in file **Request::Request(char *, int, int) threadtest.o**

Important information here is - `Request::Request(char *, int, int)` and `threadtest.o`. So, you have a source file name `threadtest.cpp` where you are instantiating `Request` object. Understand that inclusion of a header ( probably `Request.h` in `threadtest.cpp` ) helps compiler to find the declarations. Linker tries to find definitions of symbols from all object files and forms an executable.

So, possibly you are not compiling `Request.cpp` or forgot to link `Request.o`.